# CKEditor Customization

Tags: ckeditor

How can give browse for file option, in image picker instead of pointing to external link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All caps in title isn't looks good, so I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

[CKEditor 3.x File Browser (Uploader)](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29)

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php?type=Images'
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images'
});
```